# What was the role of Egypt in Soviet-Afghan war?

Tags: soviet-union, egypt, afghanistan

Just wanted to know the role of Egypt in the Soviet-Afghan war..like what did it do,who were it’s allies and enemies...I have researched on Wikipedia but didn’t find anything useful except that it had some relations with the USA...

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a quick google search on the title of your question and found a few relevant resources.  Perhaps the results below will help with some context and additional search terms?

> March 1979 marked the signing of the U.S.-backed peace agreement between Israel and Egypt. The Soviet leadership saw the agreement as giving a major advantage to the United States. A Soviet newspaper stated that Egypt and Israel were now "gendarmes of the Pentagon". The Soviets viewed the treaty not only as a peace agreement between their erstwhile allies in Egypt and the US-supported Israelis but also as a military pact.  *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet%E2%80%93Afghan_War)*

or the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/02/14/egypt-says-it-trains-afghan-rebels/a09f455a-fca0-48c0-b7fe-12e8c9bcede6/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.6e8429348ecf)

> Egypt is training Afghan rebels in guerrilla warfare and plans to arm them and send them back to Afghanistan to combat Soviet intervention forces, the Egyptian defense minister disclosed today.

or the [Institute for the Study of War](http://www.understandingwar.org/russia-and-afghanistan)
 At the time, the United States had been making headway in the Middle East at Moscow’s expense, successfully courting Egypt, Israel, Saudi Arabia, Pakistan, and others. The Soviet Union feared the loss of its communist proxy in Afghanistan.

Or the [Warfare History Network](https://warfarehistorynetwork.com/daily/military-history/afghanistan-the-soviet-unions-war-in-vietnam/)

> These were provided by the American Central Intelligence Agency, which bought weapons from sellers all over the world, including China, Egypt, and, ironically, Israel, which sold equipment it had captured during the various Arab-Israeli wars.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer above, I have information from an old Washington Post article mentioning how certain [Afghan rebels who engaged in guerilla warfare against the Soviet Union were trained by Egypt](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/02/14/egypt-says-it-trains-afghan-rebels/a09f455a-fca0-48c0-b7fe-12e8c9bcede6/).

> Egypt is training Afghan rebels in guerrilla warfare and plans to arm them and send them back to Afghanistan to combat Soviet intervention forces, the Egyptian defense minister disclosed today.

> The Egyptian assistance, announced by Gen. Kamal Hassan Ali at a news conference, underscores President Anway Sadat's growing willingness to play an active role in U.S.-led security cooperation against Soviet moves in the Middle East and South Asia. -Journalist Edward Cody, February 1980

Also, another New York Times article from the 1980s [stated that some firearms the United States gave to Afghan rebels were purchased from Egypt](https://www.nytimes.com/1981/09/23/world/sadat-says-us-buys-soviet-arms-in-egypt-for-afghan-rebels.html).